# Not able to export table into output file due to secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql, scrapy, mysql-python

I'm using windows7 and MySQL8.0. I've tried to edit the my.ini by stopping the service first. First of all, if I tried to replace my.ini with secure_file_priv = "",it was saying access denied. So, I simply saved it with 'my1.ini' then deleted the my.ini' and again renamed 'my1.ini' to 'my.ini'. Now when I try to start the MySQL80 service from administrative tools>Services, I am unable to start it again. Even I've tried this from the CLI client, but it raises the issue of secure_file_priv. How do I do it? I've been able to store the scraped data into MySQL database using Scrapy,but not able to export it to my project directory.

#pipelines.py

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
import mysql.connector

class QuotewebcrawlerPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()
        #self.dump_database()

    def create_connection(self):
        """
            This method will create the database connection & the cusror object
        """
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host = 'localhost',
                                            user = 'root',
                                            passwd = 'Pxxxx',
                                            database = 'itemcontainer'
                                        )
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def create_table(self):
        self.cursor.execute(""" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table""")
        self.cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE my_table (
                                Quote text,
                                Author text,
                                Tag text)"""
                            )

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        #print(item['quote'])
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self,item):
        """
            This method is used to write the scraped data from item container into the database
        """
        #pass
        self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(%s,%s,%s)""",(item['quote'][0],item['author'][0],
                                                                            item['tag'][0])
                            )
        self.conn.commit()
        #self.dump_database()

    # def dump_database(self):
    #     self.cursor.execute("""USE itemcontainer;SELECT * from my_table INTO OUTFILE 'quotes.txt'""",
    #                         multi = True
    #     )
    #     print("Data saved to output file")
```

#item_container.py

```
import scrapy
from ..items import QuotewebcrawlerItem

class ItemContainer(scrapy.Spider):

name = 'itemcontainer'
start_urls = [
    "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
]

def parse(self,response):

    items = QuotewebcrawlerItem()
    all_div_quotes = response.css("div.quote")
    for quotes in all_div_quotes:
        quote = quotes.css(".text::text").extract()
        author = quotes.css(".author::text").extract()
        tag = quotes.css(".tag::text").extract()

        items['quote'] = quote
        items['author'] = author
        items['tag'] = tag
        
        yield items
```

Comment: give all permissions to your my.ini and attempt to restart

Comment: @NikhilB How to give all permissions?